# How to use pgadmin python when do not have root priviledges

Tags: python, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I want to use pgadmin python as described on the pgadmin website https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python/. The problem is that the server I am on, I do not have root priviledges. I am able to `pip install pgadmin4`, but after that when I try to run `pgadmin4` on command line, I get the following error `ERROR  : Failed to create the directory /var/lib/pgadmin:`. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found by reading the documentation. Find `config.py` file in your `pgadmin4` package. Create another file `config_local.py`. Now replace `/var/lib` everywhere in `config_local.py` to some other directory.